# slice panda string in vectorised way

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to slice the string in vectorized way and answer is NaN. Although work OK if sequence index (say like str[:1]) is constant. Any help

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'NAME': ['abc','xyz','hello'], 'SEQ': [1,2,1]}) #
df['SUB'] = df['NAME'].str[:df['SEQ']]
```

The output is

```
  NAME  SEQ  SUB
0    abc    1  NaN
1    xyz    2  NaN
2  hello    1  NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately vectorized solution does not exist.

Use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with lambda function:

```
df['SUB'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['NAME'][:x['SEQ']], axis=1)
```

Or `zip` with `list comprehension` for better performance:

```
df['SUB'] = [x[:y] for x, y in zip(df['NAME'], df['SEQ'])]
```

---

```
print (df)

    NAME  SEQ SUB
0    abc    1   a
1    xyz    2  xy
2  hello    1   h
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'NAME': ['abc','xyz','hello'], 'SEQ': [1,2,1]})
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)


In [270]: %timeit df["SUB"] = df.groupby("SEQ").NAME.transform(lambda g: g.str[: g.name])
4.23 ms ± 222 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [271]: %timeit df['SUB'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['NAME'][:x['SEQ']], axis=1)
104 ms ± 2.02 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [272]: %timeit df['SUB'] = [x[:y] for x, y in zip(df['NAME'], df['SEQ'])]
785 µs ± 22.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `groupby`:

```
df["SUB"] = df.groupby("SEQ").NAME.transform(lambda g: g.str[: g.name])
```

Might make sense if there are few unique values in `SEQ`.